# How to apply some mathematical operation depending upon some particular values of particular column

Tags: bash, awk, gnuplot

I want to do some mathematical operation in some order in a text file,data.dat, using awk.
A sample file is give below, however, the original file is having m*n array,

```
-0.00309 300.0000 27.48357484
-0.00309 350.0000 27.48339634
-0.00309 400.0000 27.48309821
-0.00309 450.0000 27.48263481
-0.00309 500.0000 27.48196302
-0.00309 550.0000 27.48104749
-0.00309 600.0000 27.47986237
-0.00309 650.0000 27.47839084
-0.00309 700.0000 27.47662366
-0.00309 750.0000 27.47455745
-0.00309 800.0000 27.47219313
0.83311 50.0000 -15.61462258
0.83311 100.0000 -15.61504028
0.83311 150.0000 -15.61524246
0.83311 200.0000 -15.61547435
0.83311 250.0000 -15.61577002
0.83311 300.0000 -15.61597007
0.83311 350.0000 -15.61588681
0.83311 400.0000 -15.61538590
0.83311 450.0000 -15.61439714
0.83311 500.0000 -15.61289898
0.83311 550.0000 -15.61089993
0.83311 600.0000 -15.60842429
0.83311 650.0000 -15.60550308
0.83311 700.0000 -15.60216876
0.83311 750.0000 -15.59845261
0.83311 800.0000 -15.59438360
```

Colum one starts from negative number and after couple of rows, it change its sign (+ve).
I want to multiply colum three (in the original file it will vary) with 1e-14 when colum one has -Ve sign and with 0.5e-14 when colum one has +Ve sign.

The file is extremely large so I can not do manual operation on it.
I am able to apply the operation in entire file using

```
paste data.dat |  awk 'BEGIN{var=ARGV[1];ARGV[1]=""} {print var, $0}' "0.5e-14" | awk '{print $2, $3, $4*$1}'
```

but by doing so I can use one operation (either for -Ve or for +Ve) at a time and that is not my goal.

I want a loop in such a way that it should multiply column three with number 1e-14 if column one is negative and with 0.5e-14 if the column one is +Ve.

The expected outcome from above file is

```
-0.00309 300.0000 2.74836e-13
-0.00309 350.0000 2.74834e-13
-0.00309 400.0000 2.74831e-13
-0.00309 450.0000 2.74826e-13
-0.00309 500.0000 2.7482e-13
-0.00309 550.0000 2.7481e-13
-0.00309 600.0000 2.74799e-13
-0.00309 650.0000 2.74784e-13
-0.00309 700.0000 2.74766e-13
-0.00309 750.0000 2.74746e-13
-0.00309 800.0000 2.74722e-13
0.83311 50.0000 -7.80731e-14
0.83311 100.0000 -7.80752e-14
0.83311 150.0000 -7.80762e-14
0.83311 200.0000 -7.80774e-14
0.83311 250.0000 -7.80789e-14
0.83311 300.0000 -7.80799e-14
0.83311 350.0000 -7.80794e-14
0.83311 400.0000 -7.80769e-14
0.83311 450.0000 -7.8072e-14
0.83311 500.0000 -7.80645e-14
0.83311 550.0000 -7.80545e-14
0.83311 600.0000 -7.80421e-14
0.83311 650.0000 -7.80275e-14
0.83311 700.0000 -7.80108e-14
0.83311 750.0000 -7.79923e-14
0.83311 800.0000 -7.79719e-14
```

The operation is to be used in a gnuplut script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to use awk? For such simple things you can use gnuplot itself.
Check `help ternary`.

**Code:**

```
### conditional multiplication on columns
reset session

$Data <<EOD
-0.00309 300.0000 27.48357484
-0.00309 350.0000 27.48339634
-0.00309 400.0000 27.48309821
-0.00309 450.0000 27.48263481
-0.00309 500.0000 27.48196302
0.83311 300.0000 -15.61597007
0.83311 350.0000 -15.61588681
0.83311 400.0000 -15.61538590
0.83311 450.0000 -15.61439714
0.83311 500.0000 -15.61289898
EOD

myFactor(col1,col2) = column(col1) > 0 ? column(col2)*0.5e-14 : column(col2)*1e-14

plot $Data u 1:(myFactor(1,3)) w lp pt 7
### end of code
```

**Result:** (the data which will be plotted)

```
 -0.00309        2.74836e-13
 -0.00309        2.74834e-13
 -0.00309        2.74831e-13
 -0.00309        2.74826e-13
 -0.00309        2.7482e-13
 0.83311         -7.80731e-14
 0.83311         -7.80752e-14
 0.83311         -7.80762e-14
 0.83311         -7.80774e-14
 0.83311         -7.80789e-14
```

[image]

**Addition:**

After your descriptions, I'm still not 100% sure whether I understood what you want. Here is an attempt. Actually this is gnuplot basics.

**Code:**

```
### create 2 PNG output files
reset session

FILE = 'myData.dat'
set term pngcairo size 600,300

myFactor(col1,col2) = column(col1) > 0 ? column(col2)*0.5e-14 : column(col2)*1e-14

set output 'Column1vs2.png'
plot FILE u 1:(myFactor(1,2)) w lp pt 7 ti "Column3"

set output 'Column1vs2and3.png'
set ytics nomirror
set y2tics nomirror
plot FILE u 1:(myFactor(1,2)) axis x1y1 w lp pt 7 lc "red" ti "Column2", \
       '' u 1:(myFactor(1,3)) axis x1y2 w lp pt 7 lc "web-green" ti "Column3"

set output
### end of code
```

**Result:**
[image]

[image]

Comment: It worked for me. Could you please modify the script to do this operation on column two and column three together. Instead of column three only?

Comment: What do you actually want to plot? Modified column2 versus modified column3? `plot $Data u (myFactor(1,2)):(myFactor(1,3))`.

Comment: I want to plot column1 Vs colum2 and 3. In one case I need to do operation on only column3 while in other case I need to do operation on column 2 and 3 both.

Comment: Do you want col2 and col3 in one plot with the same x-axis (col1), but col2 with left y-axis and col3 with right y-axis or do you want two separate plots on one screen/canvas?

Comment: I want them in different plots. In One plot, it will go as: Col1 Vs col2 and col3 and in second plot, I need Col1 Vs col2.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -v n='1e-14' -v p='0.5e-14' '{$3 *= ($1>0?p:n)}1' file

-0.00309 300.0000 2.74836e-13
-0.00309 350.0000 2.74834e-13
-0.00309 400.0000 2.74831e-13
-0.00309 450.0000 2.74826e-13
-0.00309 500.0000 2.7482e-13
-0.00309 550.0000 2.7481e-13
-0.00309 600.0000 2.74799e-13
-0.00309 650.0000 2.74784e-13
-0.00309 700.0000 2.74766e-13
-0.00309 750.0000 2.74746e-13
-0.00309 800.0000 2.74722e-13
0.83311 50.0000 -7.80731e-14
0.83311 100.0000 -7.80752e-14
0.83311 150.0000 -7.80762e-14
0.83311 200.0000 -7.80774e-14
0.83311 250.0000 -7.80789e-14
0.83311 300.0000 -7.80799e-14
0.83311 350.0000 -7.80794e-14
0.83311 400.0000 -7.80769e-14
0.83311 450.0000 -7.8072e-14
0.83311 500.0000 -7.80645e-14
0.83311 550.0000 -7.80545e-14
0.83311 600.0000 -7.80421e-14
0.83311 650.0000 -7.80275e-14
0.83311 700.0000 -7.80108e-14
0.83311 750.0000 -7.79923e-14
0.83311 800.0000 -7.79719e-14
```

Comment: This worked for me. Can you please explain how the term "$1>0?p:n" works? I think ":" works like else here. Right?

Comment: Also, can you please modify this script, I want to do this operation on column two and column three together. Instead of column three only?

Comment: `$1>0?p:n` is the ternary operator, the same as `if($1>0) p else n`.  I think it's poor etiquette to modify the question after it's answered.  Currently this script does exactly what was asked in the question. However, it's very easy to apply the same pattern to the second field as well.